# Java how to make date from string

Tags: java, string, date, datetime

how can i make `Date` data type from String in java?
input: `String "2014/01/01 18:02:02"` => output: `Date 2014/01/01 18:02:02`

Comment: there are many formatter and parsing class like DateFormat , you can use anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DateFormat` to `parse` and `format` (they're reciprocal functions) the `String`. Something like,

```
String str = "2014/01/01 18:02:02";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date d = df.parse(str);
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
2014/01/01 18:02:02
```

Answer (score 1):

please use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse `String` To `Date`.

In there you can find suitable `DateFormat` to convert this `String` to `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
String dateString = "2014/01/01 18:02:02";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime StringAsDate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

I would recommend using `Time(java.time)` API instead of `java.util` for your Date & Time needs as it is new and exclusively added to java for Date & Time operations.

Comment: Since Java 8 LocalDateTime is an improvement of Date (for date+time).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet -

```
String dateString = "10-11-2014";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateInString = "2014/01/01 18:02:02";
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

It is a working and it is also suitable to you as it is not complicated. you will get this output:

```
Wed Jan 01 18:02:02 IST 2014
2014/01/01 18:02:02
```

Answer (score 0):

For your date following code should work :-

```
String myString = "2014/01/01 18:02:02";
DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
Date myDate = myDateFormat.parse(myString);
```

For more details, see the documentation for SimpleDateFormat. Just make sure you use capital "MM" for month and small "mm" for minute.